# defining a new breakable colored environment for examples

Tags: page-breaking, examples

I want to define a new colored environment for my examples. There is two title bars at top of this environment, side by side. One is filled by green color and there is a word "Example" in it. Another is filled by blue color and we write the number of example in it, for instance "1-2" (chapter 1, example 2). Finally we write the body of example in a red colored box. It may be mentioned that, this environment must have ability to be broken over pages.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  I would recommend [the `mdframed` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an improved third version, using the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package and a definition of a command `\mymdtheorem` modeled after the original `\mdtheorem`, but allowing the two colos for the title.

The environment can be used with or without an additional note and on its starred (unnumbered) version:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\colorlet{titlecolor}{green!20}
\colorlet{numbercolor}{blue!20}

\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mymdtheorem}{ O{} m o m o }%
{\ifcsdef{#2}%
{\mdf@PackageWarning{Environment #2 already exits\MessageBreak}}%
{%
\IfNoValueTF {#3}%
{%#3 not given -- number relationship
\IfNoValueTF {#5}
{%#3+#5 not given
\@definecounter{#2}%
\expandafter\xdef\csname the#2\endcsname{\@thmcounter{#2}}
\newenvironment{#2}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{#2}
\ifstrempty{##1}%
{\let\@temptitle\relax}%
{%
\def\@temptitle{\mdf@theoremseparator%
\mdf@theoremspace%
\mdf@theoremtitlefont%
##1}%
}
\begin{mdframed}[#1,frametitle={\strut #4\ \csname the#2\endcsname\@temptitle}]}%
{\end{mdframed}}%
\newenvironment{#2*}[1][]{%
\ifstrempty{##1}{\let\@temptitle\relax}{\def\@temptitle{:\ ##1}}
\begin{mdframed}[#1,frametitle={\strut#4\@temptitle}]}%
{\end{mdframed}}%
}%
{%#5 given -- reset counter
\@definecounter{#2}\@newctr{#2}[#5]%
\expandafter\xdef\csname the#2\endcsname{\@thmcounter{#2}}
\expandafter\xdef\csname the#2\endcsname{%
\expandafter\noexpand\csname the#5\endcsname \@thmcountersep
\@thmcounter{#2}}%
\newenvironment{#2}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{#2}
\ifstrempty{##1}%
{\let\@temptitle\relax}%
{%
\def\@temptitle{\mdf@theoremseparator%
\mdf@theoremspace%
\mdf@theoremtitlefont%
##1}%
}
\begin{mdframed}[#1,frametitle={\strut%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline=-0.5ex]
  \node [fill=titlecolor,anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt,xshift=-10pt] (heading) {#4};
  \node at (heading.east) [anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt] {\ \csname the#2\endcsname\@temptitle};
\end{tikzpicture}}]%
}%
{\end{mdframed}}%
\newenvironment{#2*}[1][]{%
\ifstrempty{##1}%
{\let\@temptitle\relax}%
{%
\def\@temptitle{%
\mdf@theoremspace%
\mdf@theoremtitlefont%
##1}%
}
\begin{mdframed}[#1,frametitle={\strut%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline=-0.5ex]
  \node [fill=titlecolor,anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt,xshift=-10pt] (heading) {#4};
  \node at (heading.east) [anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt] {\@temptitle};
\end{tikzpicture}}]%
}%
{\end{mdframed}}%
}%
}%
{%#3 given -- number relationship
\global\@namedef{the#2}{\@nameuse{the#3}}%
\newenvironment{#2}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{#3}
\ifstrempty{##1}%
{\let\@temptitle\relax}%
{%
\def\@temptitle{\mdf@theoremseparator%
\mdf@theoremspace%
\mdf@theoremtitlefont%
##1}%
}
\begin{mdframed}[#1,frametitle={\strut%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline=-0.5ex]
  \node [fill=titlecolor,anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt,xshift=-10pt] (heading) {#4};
  \node at (heading.east) [anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt] {\ \csname the#2\endcsname\@temptitle};
\end{tikzpicture}}]%
}%
{\end{mdframed}}%
\newenvironment{#2*}[1][]{%
\ifstrempty{##1}{\let\@temptitle\relax}{\def\@temptitle{:\ ##1}}
\begin{mdframed}[#1,frametitle={\strut%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline=-0.5ex]
  \node [fill=titlecolor,anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt,xshift=-10pt] (heading) {#4};
  \node at (heading.east) [anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt] {\@temptitle};
\end{tikzpicture}}]%
}%
{\end{mdframed}}%
}%
}%
}
\makeatother
\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
hidealllines,
frametitlerule=true,%
frametitlebackgroundcolor=numbercolor,
frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
backgroundcolor=red!20,
splittopskip=1.2\topskip,splitbottomskip=.6\topskip,
}
\mymdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{example}{Example}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\begin{example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}\par\bigskip
\begin{example*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example*}\par\bigskip
\begin{example}[A numbered example with a note]
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}\par\bigskip
\begin{example*}[An unnumbered example with a note]
\lipsum[2]
\end{example*}

\end{document}
```

An image of one of the frames:

[image]

And here's an image of the full document obtained (as can be seen, the environment admits page breakings):

[image]

Using `firstextra`, `middleextra` and `secondextra` one can produce "closed frames" and a continuation text (as was suggested by **azetina** in a comment) for the case in which a page break occurs inside the examples:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\colorlet{titlecolor}{green!20}
\colorlet{numbercolor}{blue!20}

\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mymdtheorem}{ O{} m o m o }%
{\ifcsdef{#2}%
{\mdf@PackageWarning{Environment #2 already exits\MessageBreak}}%
{%
\IfNoValueTF {#3}%
{%#3 not given -- number relationship
\IfNoValueTF {#5}
{%#3+#5 not given
\@definecounter{#2}%
\expandafter\xdef\csname the#2\endcsname{\@thmcounter{#2}}
\newenvironment{#2}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{#2}
\ifstrempty{##1}%
{\let\@temptitle\relax}%
{%
\def\@temptitle{\mdf@theoremseparator%
\mdf@theoremspace%
\mdf@theoremtitlefont%
##1}%
}
\begin{mdframed}[#1,frametitle={\strut #4\ \csname the#2\endcsname\@temptitle}]}%
{\end{mdframed}}%
\newenvironment{#2*}[1][]{%
\ifstrempty{##1}{\let\@temptitle\relax}{\def\@temptitle{:\ ##1}}
\begin{mdframed}[#1,frametitle={\strut#4\@temptitle}]}%
{\end{mdframed}}%
}%
{%#5 given -- reset counter
\@definecounter{#2}\@newctr{#2}[#5]%
\expandafter\xdef\csname the#2\endcsname{\@thmcounter{#2}}
\expandafter\xdef\csname the#2\endcsname{%
\expandafter\noexpand\csname the#5\endcsname \@thmcountersep
\@thmcounter{#2}}%
\newenvironment{#2}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{#2}
\ifstrempty{##1}%
{\let\@temptitle\relax}%
{%
\def\@temptitle{\mdf@theoremseparator%
\mdf@theoremspace%
\mdf@theoremtitlefont%
##1}%
}
\begin{mdframed}[#1,frametitle={\strut%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline=-0.5ex]
  \node [fill=titlecolor,anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt,xshift=-10pt] (heading) {#4};
  \node at (heading.east) [anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt] {\ \csname the#2\endcsname\@temptitle};
\end{tikzpicture}}]%
}%
{\end{mdframed}}%
\newenvironment{#2*}[1][]{%
\ifstrempty{##1}%
{\let\@temptitle\relax}%
{%
\def\@temptitle{%
\mdf@theoremspace%
\mdf@theoremtitlefont%
##1}%
}
\begin{mdframed}[#1,frametitle={\strut%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline=-0.5ex]
  \node [fill=titlecolor,anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt,xshift=-10pt] (heading) {#4};
  \node at (heading.east) [anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt] {\@temptitle};
\end{tikzpicture}}]%
}%
{\end{mdframed}}%
}%
}%
{%#3 given -- number relationship
\global\@namedef{the#2}{\@nameuse{the#3}}%
\newenvironment{#2}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{#3}
\ifstrempty{##1}%
{\let\@temptitle\relax}%
{%
\def\@temptitle{\mdf@theoremseparator%
\mdf@theoremspace%
\mdf@theoremtitlefont%
##1}%
}
\begin{mdframed}[#1,frametitle={\strut%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline=-0.5ex]
  \node [fill=titlecolor,anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt,xshift=-10pt] (heading) {#4};
  \node at (heading.east) [anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt] {\ \csname the#2\endcsname\@temptitle};
\end{tikzpicture}}]%
}%
{\end{mdframed}}%
\newenvironment{#2*}[1][]{%
\ifstrempty{##1}{\let\@temptitle\relax}{\def\@temptitle{:\ ##1}}
\begin{mdframed}[#1,frametitle={\strut%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,baseline=-0.5ex]
  \node [fill=titlecolor,anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt,xshift=-10pt] (heading) {#4};
  \node at (heading.east) [anchor=west,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=6.5pt] {\@temptitle};
\end{tikzpicture}}]%
}%
{\end{mdframed}}%
}%
}%
}
\makeatother
\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
hidealllines,
frametitlerule=true,%
frametitlebackgroundcolor=numbercolor,
frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
backgroundcolor=red!20,
splittopskip=1.5\topskip,splitbottomskip=\topskip,
firstextra={%
    \draw (P|-O) -- +(-\textwidth,0);
  },
middleextra={%
    \node[draw,anchor=west,yshift=0.7cm,fill=titlecolor] at (P-|O) {\bfseries Example~\theexample~Continued};
    \draw (O-|P) -- +(\textwidth,0);
  },
  secondextra={%
    \node[draw,anchor=west,yshift=0.7cm,fill=titlecolor,inner xsep=8pt] at (P-|O) {\bfseries Example~\theexample~Continued};
    \draw (P-|O) -- +(\textwidth,0);
  }
}
\mymdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{example}{Example}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}

\begin{example}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This continuation text might be redundant since the colored frame indicates a continuation, but I just wanted to illustrate some of the powerful features of `mdframed`.

Comment: It would be interesting if instead of just breaking across pages, that the example environment breaks with a `Example 1 Continued` type of heading on the other pages. Just saying...

Comment: @azetina your wish is my command ;-) Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Can the frame be closed at the bottom of page one and closed at the top of page 2? Depending on the the desired example environment, the consistency of the title design of the continuation should match the initial defined environment. As it is, the second break is fine but a bit inconsistent with what is on page one. :-)

Comment: @azetina sure, it can be done. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: running this code, the width of first part and middle part are bigger than \textwidth, but last part is equal to \textwidth. for example, when i use "userdefinedwidth=.9\textwidth", the last part gets thinner but not about first and second parts. it also happens when i use "outermargin=10", for instance. how can i set just these two parts?

Comment: @smh I need to see a simple minimal and complete document with the settings used. Please compose this minimal document and upload the code elsewhere or ask a follow-up question.

Comment: since i use "xepersian" package, and mdframed is not supported by xepersian, the above problem occurs. is there any other package to do "define a new breakable colored environment for examples"?

Comment: @smh the only other one that I know, but it's not as versatile as `mdframed`, is [framed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed) and I don't know if it supposrts `xepersian`. Perhaps you could open a new question?

Comment: In your second example: If the content of the example environment is longer e.g. lipsum[1-10] I get some confusing results. That is, I get content on the first page, second page is blank, and third page has content. Do you get the same error? And if so, how could this be solved?